# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'. null object

Tags: function, flutter, checkbox, flutter-layout

**here is my code**
**and error is after fluttre update to 2.13 version so please help....**
**error is on TaskCheckBox  class onchanged method**
**and dart analys return  The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'.**

```
class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskTileState createState() => _TaskTileState();
}

class _TaskTileState extends State<TaskTile> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        'This is task.',
        style: TextStyle(
          decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: TaskCheckBox(checkboxState: isChecked,toggleCheckboxState: (bool checkboxState) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = checkboxState;
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}

class TaskCheckBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool checkboxState;
  final Function toggleCheckboxState;

  TaskCheckBox({required this.checkboxState,required this.toggleCheckboxState});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      value: checkboxState,
      onChanged: toggleCheckboxState,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try this:

onChanged: () => toggleCheckboxState,

Comment: Still, this error occur.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an function that expect receive an boolean value, but in TaskCheckBox you are receiving a normal function
Also the Checkbox expect receive the same type, a function with a bool value

Change to this

```
final Function(bool) toggleCheckboxState;
```

Final result

```
 class TaskCheckBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool checkboxState;
  final Function(bool) toggleCheckboxState;

  TaskCheckBox({
    @required this.checkboxState,
    @required this.toggleCheckboxState,
  });
```

Comment: I did not see it, but you are missing @ in required, check the edit

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this on a different post [error: The argument type 'void Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68003129/16027681)

i updated the `checkboxCallback` method into this:

```
void checkBoxCallBack(bool? checkBoxState) {
    if (checkBoxState != null) {
      setState(() {
        isChecked = checkBoxState;
      });
    }
  }
```

and the `onChanged:` property of `Checkbox` into this:

```
onChanged: toggleCheckboxState as void Function(bool?)?,
```

it get rids the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and then I figured it out by combining the answer of **theowl-0011** with **p2kr**
Please review my method. It works...

Just change `toggleCheckBox:` to this:

```
    (bool? checkBoxState) {
    if (checkBoxState != null) {
      setState(() {
        isChecked = checkBoxState;
      });
    }
```

And `final Function toggleCheckbox;` to:

```
 final Function(bool?) toggleCheckbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same I got The argument type `Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?`.

I changed the line

```
final Function toggleCheckbox;
```

to

```
final Function(bool?) toggleCheckbox;
```

and that fixed it.