# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

While I was making an app an error occurred says- The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'. inside **Taskcheckbox** stateless widget at `onChanged : toggleCheckState` says the function `toggleCheckboxState` can't be assigned.

```
class task_tile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<task_tile> createState() => _task_tileState();

}

class _task_tileState extends State<task_tile> {
  bool ischanged = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("This is a box",style: TextStyle(
          decoration: ischanged ? TextDecoration.lineThrough:null
      ),
      ),
      trailing: Taskcheckbox(ischanged,(bool checkboxState) {
        setState(() {
          ischanged = checkboxState;
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}

class Taskcheckbox extends StatelessWidget {

final bool checkboxState;
final  Function toggleCheckboxState;

Taskcheckbox(this.checkboxState,this.toggleCheckboxState);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      value: checkboxState,
      onChanged:toggleCheckboxState,
    );
      }
  }
```

Comment: Needs changes in declaration check answer. please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: The argument type 'void Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68003129/error-the-argument-type-void-functionbool-cant-be-assigned-to-the-paramete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chnage your function type to solve this issue

From

```
final Function toggleCheckboxState;
```

To

```
final ValueChanged<bool?> toggleCheckboxState;
```

Comment: when i replace it by ValueChanged  new error arrived   at  trailing: Taskcheckbox(ischanged,(bool checkboxState) {
        setState(() {
          ischanged = checkboxState;
        });
      }),The argument type 'void Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'.

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: Okay just remove bool from (bool checkboxState) and keep it (checkboxState) only

Comment: Upvote and mark as answered fi worked, Thanks

Comment: Pleased to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You use this

```
final  Function toggleCheckboxState;
```

to

```
final Function(Object?) toggleCheckboxState;
```

Comment: working but giving erron on  trailing: Taskcheckbox(ischanged,(bool checkboxState) {
        setState(() {
          ischanged = checkboxState;
        });
      }),  The argument type 'void Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code changes

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      value: checkboxState,
      onChanged: (bool val) {
        toggleCheckboxState();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: The argument type 'void Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'.